# Terminology How to describe a query function without using cache underlying?

Tags: terminology

I have two versions of query function, one will cache the last result, another will not. I prefer make the cache-version to be default one, and let its API name without any suffix. (example: readVal())

What terms should I use to describe the non-cache-version function name?

- readValFresh()?
- readValVolatile()?
- loadAgain()?
- readValTruly()?

Is there a precise english word or terms to describe this case?

Comment: You could use the prefix `get` instead of `read` for the query that is not using cache.

Comment: I like get vs. find but maybe not the best question for SO.